# How to encode array data (Uint8Array) for instruction?

Tags: transactions, instructions

I am trying to call a function using a non-anchor program from solana.  The function takes a [u8:32] argument as "seeds" and a u32 argument as "number_of_schedules".  I have looked all over the docs online and no information on this is available, or they only show how to encode basic data like instruction index.  Here is my layout:

```
  const dataLayout = BufferLayout.struct([
    BufferLayout.u8('instruction'),
    BufferLayout.u32('seeds'), // I don't think this is right; should be [u8; 32] but can't find that
    BufferLayout.u32('number_of_schedules')
  ]);
  const data = Buffer.alloc(dataLayout.span);
  dataLayout.encode(
    {
      instruction: 0, // 0 for create instruction,
      seeds: seeds,
      number_of_schedules: new BN(3),
    },
    data,
  );
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

An array of fixed length can be expressed as follows:

```
BufferLayout.seq(BufferLayout.u8('seed'), 32, 'seeds')
```

A sequence (labelled `'seeds'`) of `u8` elements (labeled `'seed'`), of length 32.